# Is there any way to realize if a number is truncated due to conversion?

Tags: c++

In a big code in C++ there are many calculations and castings (to different data types) to get in the end a float number, this number is being truncated or rounded somewhere in these big calculations and castings.

For example instead of getting the right and precise number 0.2500992 I get rounded number 0.2501.

1. Is there any compiler warnings if the number will be truncated due to conversion ?
2. Is there any known software that may go over the code and tells me what number may be truncated?
3. In which situation truncation of float number will happen (when converting to which data type)?
4. Does compiler round up float number? Can I tell compiler not to round up?

Thanks

Comment: Hold on, `0.2501` is not representable by a `float`, so you definitely didn't get that!

Comment: which data type has higher precision than float?

Comment: Undo the conversion and see whether you get the value you started with?  The `double` type usually has about twice the precision of `float` (32-bit vs 64-bit values); the `long double` type may or may not be more precise still.  However, there's no guarantee; all three could map to the same underlying type and have the same precision.

Comment: @Oli: for that matter neither is `0.2500992`. They differ by about 6.5 times `FLT_EPSILON`, so I think that's 13 ulps. Might be 26, I'm not great with this stuff ;-) This is a noticeable error but not massive considering that there are "many calculations".

Comment: I just didn't get it, you say double has twice precision of float and in the other hand you say all three may have the same precision ? what sentence is correct?

Comment: @Nizarazo: the only common thing in floating-point that rounds in base 10, is when you print the value. So first of all, when you're trying to track down this kind of thing make sure that you always print your values out with way too many digits. For 32 bit IEEE floats, "way too many digits" is more than 24, for example use `%.30f` with `printf` or `cout << setprecision(30)`.

Comment: The obligatory [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there is a small error happened when subtracting two floating point numbers, I did the calculation using another method which is ceil() and 1 floating point manipulation instead of three floating point manipulations (first method).

It gives different result but the two results are constant either 0.2500992 or 0.2501.

In my opinion the solution is the method with ceil since it has less floating point manipulations small errors.

here is my code to explain clearly the issue I am facing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PARTS_PER_MILLION 1000000
#define FLOATING_POINT_ERROR 0.00001

int main()
{
  float ppm_f free_hd_ports;
  float totalAllocatedVideoParties = 1.749899983406066894531250000000;
  float num_hd720_vid_ports= 1.749899983406066894531250000000;
  unsigned short min_video_parties = 30,numVidHD720Parties = 28,numVidCifParties = 84,numVidHDParties;
  char buffer[25];
  unsigned long ppm1,ppm2;

//method 1
  numVidHD720Parties = floor(min_video_parties - totalAllocatedVideoParties);       
  free_hd_ports = (float)min_video_parties - totalAllocatedVideoParties;

  ppm_f = (free_hd_ports - numVidHD720Parties);

  printf("ppm_f calculated by method with floating point subsctraction: %.20f\n",ppm_f);

//method 2
  numVidHDParties  = (unsigned short)ceil(num_hd720_vid_ports);
  ppm_f = ((float)numVidHDParties) - num_hd720_vid_ports;

  printf("ppm_f calculated by ceil method: %.20f\n",ppm_f);
}
```

Screen:

```
ppm_f calculated by method with floating point subsctraction: 0.25009918212890625000
ppm_f calculated by ceil method: 0.25010001659393310547
```

This example shows the the floating point calculation error described in the below link as mentioned before:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Answer is not helpful for anyone else reading it. What do you do differently in the two calculations (normally, computers are pretty deterministic at calculations...) and how do you know which one has the higher precision?

Comment: Sebastian it is not fair to reduce one point after giving the full answer

Comment: Didn't reduce AFTER you gave the full answer. Now the answer is more useful, so there you go - point is back. Satisfied?